# Python Pandas value-dependent column creation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns "Time" and "A". For each row, df["Time"] is an integer timestamp and df["A"] is a float.  I want to create a new column "B" which has the value of df["A"], but the one that occurs at or immediately before five seconds in the future.  I can do this iteratively as:

```
for i in df.index:
    df["B"][i] = df["A"][max(df[df["Time"] <= df["Time"][i]+5].index)]
```

However, the df has tens of thousands of records so this takes far too long, and I need to run this a few hundred times so my solution isn't really an option.  I am somewhat new to pandas (and only somewhat less new to programming in general) so I'm not sure if there's an obvious solution to this supported by pandas.

It would help if I had a way of referencing the specific value of df["Time"] in each row while creating the column, so I could do something like:

```
df["B"] = df["A"][max(df[df["Time"] <= df["Time"][corresponding_row]+5].index)]
```

Thanks.

Edit:  Here's an example of what my goal is.  If the dataframe is as follows:

```
Time A
0    0
1    1
4    2
7    3
8    4
10   5
12   6
15   7
18   8
20   9
```

then I would like the result to be:

```
Time A  B
0    0  2
1    1  2
4    2  4
7    3  6
8    4  6
10   5  7
12   6  7
15   7  9
18   8  9
20   9  9
```

where each line in B comes from the value of A in the row with Time greater by at most 5.  So if Time is the index as well, then df["B"][0] = df["A"][4] since 4 is the largest time which is at most 5 greater than 0.  In code, 4 = max(df["Time"][df["Time"] <= 0+5], which is why df["B"][0] is df["A"][4].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [tshift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#shifting-lagging). You may need to resample first to fill in any missing values. I don't have time to test this, but try this.

```
df['B'] = df.resample('s', how='ffill').tshift(5, freq='s').reindex_like(df)
```

And a tip for getting help here: if you provide a few rows of sample data and an example of your desired result, it's easy for us to copy/paste and try out a solution for you.

**Edit**

OK, looking at your example data, let's leave your Time column as integers.

```
In [59]: df
Out[59]: 
      A
Time   
0     0
1     1
4     2
7     3
8     4
10    5
12    6
15    7
18    8
20    9
```

Make an array containing the first and last Time values and all the integers in between.

```
In [60]: index = np.arange(df.index.values.min(), df.index.values.max() + 1)
```

Make a new DataFrame with all the gaps filled in.

```
In [61]: df1 = df.reindex(index, method='ffill')
```

Make a new column with the same data shifted up by 5 -- that is, looking forward in time by 5 seconds.

```
In [62]: df1['B'] = df1.shift(-5)
```

And now drop all the filled-in times we added, taking only values from the original Time index.

```
In [63]: df1.reindex(df.index)
Out[63]: 
      A   B
Time       
0     0   2
1     1   2
4     2   4
7     3   6
8     4   6
10    5   7
12    6   7
15    7   9
18    8 NaN
20    9 NaN
```

How you fill in the last values, for which there is no "five seconds later" is up to you. Judging from your desired output, maybe use `fillna` with a constant value set to the last value in column A.

Comment: If I understand what this line does correctly, it just increases the time by 5 seconds.  What I want is, for each row, to search through the dataframe and find the row which is timestamped about 5 seconds later, and take the entry in column "A" of that row.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does what you want. Each element of 'B' is 'A' five seconds in the future. Maybe it's -5, not 5... try it out.

Comment: When I run this on df["A"] instead of df, I get all NaNs.  I checked the df and it doesn't have any entries that are NaN.  I also ran it without the resample operation in there and the same thing happened.  When I ran it on df["Time"] after converting it to a column of datetime objects, it just added 5 seconds to each time.  I think part of the trouble for me is that I don't really understand the resample operation (and can't find any tutorials or explanations online) so I don't know how to tweak the function to help me.